# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in IngredientsController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a newby at Rails. I hope anyone can help me with, which i am sure, is kinda logical as soon as i figured out why it doesnt work as i expect.

I have a destroy method that actually wprks. It destroys what i want, but i get an error that the id could not be found.

Thanks in advance.

The Error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in IngredientsController#destroy
Couldn't find Ingredient with id=38

My ingredient controller:

```
def destroy
  @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id])
  @ingredient.destroy
  flash[:notice] = @ingredient.ingredient + ' is succesvol verwijderd'
  redirect_to '/recipes/'
end
```

My routes:

```
    Website::Application.routes.draw do

      root 'recipes#index'

      resources :recipes, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update, :create, :new, :index, :show]   
         do
       resources :ingredients
      end

      get 'ingredients/:id/destroy' => 'ingredients#destroy'
      get '/find' => 'recipes#find'

      get 'recipes/find' => 'recipes#find'
      get 'recipes/:id/destroy' => 'recipes#destroy'
      post 'recipes/:id/edit' => 'recipes#update'

      get 'recipes/edit' => 'recipes#edit'
      get 'recipes/update' => 'recipes#index'
      post 'recipes/new' => 'recipes#create'

      get 'ingredients/show' => 'ingredients#show'
      get 'ingredients/create' => 'recipes#edit'
      get 'ingredients/edit' => 'ingredients#edit'
```

The code in the html.erb

```
<table>
<th>ing_id</th>
<th>Ingredient</th>
<th>Hoeveelheid</th>
<th>Eenheid</th>
<th>recipe_id</th>
<th>delete</th>
<% @ingredient.each do |ingredients| %>

  <tr>
  <td><%= ingredients.id %></td>
  <td><%= ingredients.ingredient %></td>
  <td><%= ingredients.amount %></td>
  <td><%= ingredients.unit %></td>
  <td><%= ingredients.recipe_id %></td>
  <td><a href='/ingredients/<%= ingredients.id %>/destroy'>Delete</a></td>
  </tr>

<% end %>
```

Comment: u are using @ingredient in flash after destroying it

Comment: take a backup of it before destroying it and use that backup instance in flash

Comment: Or just swap the lines, of `flash[:notice]` and ` .destroy`

Comment: You know that you can pass `only` and `except` to `resource(s)`? Like, `resource :ingredients, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]`.

Comment: @pduersteler, i didn't know about the except. But how can it help me in this case?

Comment: That was just an information for you, but nothing that may help in this case unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already destroyed your instance of `@ingredient` before you called flash, your flash[:notice] can't find an @ingredient to render. Do this instead:

```
flash[:notice] = @ingredient.ingredient + ' is succesvol verwijderd'
@ingredient.destroy
```

Comment: Hi thanks, for the quick response. I have tried your solution, but unfortunally that wasnt the problem. I even deleted the flash notice, didnt worked either. I have done the same things for the recipe. The destroy and notice after it, like in my ingredient_controller. There it works. So i am staring at the screen and cant figure it out.

Comment: Could you include your stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem in my redirect (or honestly, maybe sometimes else, I tried a lot). But what finally worked was getting my ingredients_controller looking like this:

```
  def destroy
    @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id])
    @ingredient.destroy
    flash[:notice] = @ingredient.ingredient + ' is succesvol verwijderd'
    redirect_to edit_recipe_path(@recipe)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u check `@ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id])` if it is available. Check for the params what comes from view.  Try with the same code in rails console to verify the results and database content.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that the `destroy` action is not the problem. As you said, it is working correctly and deleting the resource. What it looks like is:

You are trying to access the deleted Ingredient model after it was destroy. This will cause the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error since the first thing the destroy action does is fetch the resource.

*or*

You are attempting to delete the same Ingredient model again. If you are on the show page for the resource and refresh it after you destroy the resource you will get the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` since the resource no longer exists.